# Watching an Entire Repo in Jira

Tags: jira

I'm trying to watch an entire Jira repo (Mesos) and can't seem to find a way to get email notification a la Github for each update. Closest I got was here:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-4203

Is this possible if I'm not a project admin?

Comment: it's a legitimate question. I'm just curious, why do you need(want) emails for each movement in the jira world? jira is in itself a working place, with lots of dashboarding capabilities to keep an eye on an entire project (or several projects). In our projects the jira admin arranges these settings (to send notifications to the team). I'm not sure how email notifications about ALL issues and updates help someone in a productive way.

Comment: It's just part of our flow on GH, and I wanted to see if we could mimic it in Jira

Answer (score 1):

I found when I was using JIRA on a regular basis that notifications were reliable but you actually have to turn them on in two places.  One is within the Space or Project you wanted to "Watch", the other was within your profile settings. I needed to enable notifications at the profile level before any of my watched spaces would send me an email.  HTH.